# Будет ли состояние гонок, если один поток меняет переменную типа bool, а другой читает из неё?

Tags: многопоточность, c++

Существует 2 потока, один из которых читает данные из переменной типа bool, а другой может менять её значение.

Являются ли эти две операции атомарными по отношению друг к другу?

А если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь стандартную обертку, чтобы сделать монопольный доступ к этой переменной.
Разумеется, можно сделать метод доступа, который бы синхронизировал доступ, но мне не хочется изобретать велосипед.

Используются ОС Unix

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Операции не могут быть атомарными *по отношению друг к другу,* они либо *атомарные,* либо *неатомарные.*
- Собственно, если переформулировать ваш вопрос как *"Являются ли `read` и `write` для `bool` атомарными?",* то на него уже можно попытаться ответить.
- А ответ достаточно простой - **нет, не являются.**

> - Атомарность этих операций нигде не специфицирована, поскольку она зависит от архитектуры машины, на которой выполняется скомпилированный код. Так, чтение `bool` в `unaligned` случае вполне может привести к генерированию `2+` инструкций.
> - Вторая проблема - [**когерентность кэшей.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) Операция должна быть инвариантной относительно всех кэшей процессора, а значит потенциально она перестает быть атомарной.

---

- *Теперь чуть ближе к практике.* В новом стандарте `C++11` для гарантированной атомарности операций над интегральными типами следует использовать [**`std::atomic_bool`.**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)
- Если используется `boost`, то лично я бы *(не знаком с вашей задачей и тыкаю пальцем в небо)* организовал сихронизацию при работе с переменной типа `bool` с помощью **[`boost::condition_variable`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref)**
- Возможно, вам подойдет использование *(специфично для `WinAPI`)* [**Interlocked функций**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122.aspx) для доступа к переменной или же, например, какой-нибудь классический механизм синхронизации типа [**Critical Section.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908.aspx)
- `...`

---

- Подробнее по поводу атомарности операций `read / write`, их архитектурозависимости и про `Microsoft-specific` обещания касательно применения `volatile` можно почитать [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic) и [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995310/is-volatile-bool-for-thread-control-considered-wrong)

Comment: Дополню, что в gcc (раз речь о Unix, то, вполне вероятно, он) есть [atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html). Это как некий аналог Interlocked-функций.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, откуда вы только все это знаете....

Comment: 2 @drdaeman: это называется ловкость рук и никакого мошенничества :)

Answer (score 1):

Самый типичный случай гонки. Просто так атомарными эти операции не будут. Для синхронизации надо использовать мьютексы или семафоры. Конкретная реализация зависит от операционной системы, а также от того, как Вы организуете многопоточность: используя низкоуровневые API или обертки.